# Link Drupal Node Content to a CiviCRM user and add user to a group?

Tags: drupal, groups, drupal-rules

I am trying to add the current user logged in to the Drupal 7 site to a CiviCRM group when they add content. For example we have a business directory and the signed in user can submit their listing. I want the user who submits the listing to be added a CiviCRM group called business directory which can then be used to email them in the future.

I tried using the contact reference field but this allows me to select the user. We want it to automatically select the signed in user.

Further, I am trying to get the rule to add the user to the group.

Has anyone achieved this with Drupal 7 & CiviCRM 4.7X.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use rules module where you set condition upon node submit to perform to add user to CiviCRM group.

Module: Rules/ CiviRules

Comment: Hi Pradeep. I have tried that but I can't seem to get the rules to work. It does not fetch the right details to add in the data selector. Any ideas?

Comment: What details are you looking for??

Comment: Also - you may need to have `civicrm_entity` installed as well.

Comment: Thanks Guys. @PradeepNayak - I am having trouble with the data selector to add the Contact to the CiviCRM Group. I will edit the question and link an image there. I have installed the civicrm_entity module.

Comment: For anyone looking for the answer I have added this below.

Answer (score 1):

On a node update (You can change it to node create) it captures the email address from the node i.e. directory and creates a new Drupal user and CiviCRM contact and assigns that contact to the group.

```
{ "rules_add_new_user_to_civicrm_group_working" : {
    "LABEL" : "Add New User to CiviCRM Group - Working with New User",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "ACTIVE" : false,
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "civicrm", "civicrm_entity" ],
    "ON" : { "node_update--directory" : { "bundle" : "directory" } },
    "DO" : [
      { "entity_create" : {
          "USING" : {
            "type" : "user",
            "param_name" : "[node:title]",
            "param_mail" : "[node:field-directory-email]"
          },
          "PROVIDE" : { "entity_created" : { "entity_created" : "Created entity" } }
        }
      },
      { "entity_save" : { "data" : [ "entity-created" ], "immediate" : "1" } },
      { "civicrm_entity_action_load_create_contact" : {
          "USING" : { "user" : [ "entity-created" ], "email" : [ "" ] },
          "PROVIDE" : { "civicrm_contact" : { "civicrm_contact" : "Created or Loaded CiviCRM Contact" } }
        }
      },
      { "civicrm_entity_query" : {
          "USING" : {
            "type" : "civicrm_contact",
            "property" : "id",
            "value" : [ "civicrm-contact:id" ]
          },
          "PROVIDE" : { "entity_fetched" : { "entity_fetched" : "Fetched CiviCRM entity list" } }
        }
      },
      { "civicrm_entity_rules_action_assign_contact_to_group" : {
          "contact" : [ "entity-fetched:0:contact-id-contact" ],
          "group_id" : { "value" : { "2" : "2" } }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```